# List Assignment Out of Index range wile trying to replace values in a list according to other list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am not able to identify error in my below code which returns list assignment out of range

```
bool_list=[False, False, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True]
b_list=[4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14]
```

For above I tried to write a for loop which goes to index and sets a new value

```
    for i in b_list:
       bool_list[i]= False
```

Comment: Indices are zero-based, `14` is outside the bounds

Comment: bool_list[i-1]= False

Comment: bool_list[i-1] = False does not work as it replaces 3rd index value rather than 4th index.

Answer (score 0):

`bool_list[14]` does not exist. You have 14 elements in the `bool_list`, with indexes from 0 to 13. Remember, in Python indexes start at 0, not at 1

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be due to the size of both the list, i don't really program in pyhton but i think the problem is that you take I from b_list which could be the number 10 and use it to index the bool_list whereas the bool_list might not have the 10th element